# How can I use ORM-like queries on a Map?

Tags: dictionary, go

I have created a slice of structs that has 3 properties

```
type Person struct {
  age int
  gender string
  name string
}
```

How can I pull the item from the slice which matches my criteria?

For example I would like to do

```
var persons []Person = mySliceOfPersons
person := getFrom(persons).Where(age ==10).Where(gender == "male")
```

The purpose here is to keep the data in memory, and not be restricted by IO. (I'm expecting thousands of calls per second). I am new to Go and I am not sure where to find a package that does this.  The data comes from Json and not a Database so I don't think I can use the sql package.

Comment: I don't think GO has anything like that out of the box. There may be some library though.

Comment: Please don't confuse SQL which is a standardized language, with ORM-like method calls. This approach could be however be compared to LINQ. There is a library that implements that sort of thing, but I really don't recommend such a solution, because it is far from idiomatic.

Comment: @AlexGitelman Any ideas what such a library might be called? searching for linq, sql,query etc, has only gotten me database libraries.

Comment: googling for "go linq library" leads to http://ahmetalpbalkan.github.io/go-linq/ which is the library I knew.

Comment: @SirDarius what would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 0):

This solution IS a database, but you can embed it into your application for use rather than relying on an outside db: https://github.com/HouzuoGuo/tiedot

Another possibility is an approach like this one, which uses the sql package against local flat files, which could potentially be adapted to run against map?: https://github.com/dinedal/textql